# TexStudio (Win. 7): Don't show the full filename in the tab

Tags: texstudio, windows

I could not find a solution to this "issue" of mine so I decided to ask the question myself. As the title says, for each open file/.tex document, is it possible to omit the rest of its filename with an ellipsis or anything similar if it is too long? I sometimes have .tex files with relatively long names, and the consequence of this is that I can sometimes only see two files open. Instead of using the mouse to select a certain file, say A, I have to press the arrows to the right of the files in view a few times until A appears.
I hope my description made sense.

[image]
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot to illustrate your problem? My Tab bar looks like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/OYcv6.png Is this what you want?

Comment: Using the right mouse button where the tabs are located gives you a list of all your open files.

Comment: @samcarter That's true. I will post a picture in a few minutes!

Comment: @samcarter Exactly! Did I misconfigure TeXStudio in some way, or did I miss an option in the settings?

Comment: If I miss something of  MSDOS times is that no one tortured you with endless filenames filled with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

**[Unfortunatly not working for Windows]**

The appearance of the let's call it tab-bar is related to the chosen style (to be selected under `Preferences->General->Appearance->Style`)

For example `Cleanlooks` displays the long names:

[image]

while `default` shortens the names up to a minimal lenght:

[image]

**[On Windows]**

There had been a related feature request (https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/397/), but it was closed.

Comment: Sorry, but the default style is already "default." Here is a picture: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22353078/textstudioSettings.png

Comment: mmmm, looks like this depends on the operating system. I have a total different set of style on a mac.

Comment: Ah, lucky you! It seems that no matter what style I change to, the names' length remain the same. I do wonder if it is just not possible on the Windows version yet.

Comment: So the actual answer to this question is "Change to linux" :)

Comment: Haha, a drastic measure. Maybe I will do that after finishing my study. ;-)

Comment: @AramtheSquirrel related: https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/397/

Comment: Interesting. It seems it was requested in 2013, but the arrows I mentioned are the way of handling this (on Windows). So since this was denied as a feature request, do you know if I should just delete this question then?

Comment: @AramtheSquirrel leave it open. Perhaps there is a hidden way I just don't know? And it might be useful for other (non-windows) user with this problem.